# what is the correct form syntax and related jquery to get a json array

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, json

I know that how the json should looks like. It's an array with elements (A,B,C) and each element has 4 diffent values in an array.

```
{
"A":["157","219","",""],
"B":["157","576","",""],
"C":["654","341","",""]
}
```

**Tried solution 1:**

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#btn_save', function(){
    var data = jQuery('#hetfo_form').serialize();
    console.log(data);
});


<button type="button" id="#btn_save"></button>
```

Yes, I don't submit the form with submit event but read the content of the form when I click on the button which is outside of the form.

```
<form id="hetfo_form" action="#" method="post">
<select class="form-control" name="A[]">
        <option value="2">......</option>
        <option value="3">......</option>
        ...
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="A[]">
        <option value="2">......</option>
        <option value="3">......</option>
        ...
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="B[]">
        <option value="2">......</option>
        <option value="3">......</option>
        ...
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="B[]">
        <option value="2">......</option>
        <option value="3">......</option>
        ...
</select>

<select class="form-control" name="C[]">
        <option value="2">......</option>
        <option value="3">......</option>
        ...
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="C[]">
        <option value="2">......</option>
        <option value="3">......</option>
        ...
</select>

</form>
```

The result of the above code on the console looks like this:
A%5B%5D=2&A%5B%5D=&A%5B%5D=40&A%5B%5D=775&A%5B%5D=3&A%5B%5D=‌​&A%5B%5D=&A%5B%5D=&A‌​%5B%5D=&A%5B%5D=&A%5‌​B%5D=&A%5B%5D=

It looks like even I write select name="C[]" it is not recognized as array C but a variable called C[] . The brackets "[" "]" handled as regular string.

If I use serializeArray() the the result is: 
[serializeArray result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9xvl.png)

**Tried solution 2:**
I also tried to create this function:

```
 function ConvertFormToJSON(form){
     var array = jQuery(form).serializeArray();
     var json = {};

     jQuery.each(array, function() {
         json[this.name] = this.value || '';
     });

     return json;
 }
```

Then assigned the return value the data variable:

```
  jQuery(document).on('click', '#btn_save', function(){
    var data =ConvertFormToJSON('#hetfo_form');
    console.log(data);
 });
```

[The result on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz3Pu.png)

**Tried solution 3:**

```
 var data =JSON.stringify(jQuery('#hetfo_form').serializeArray());
```

Result on console:
[{"name":"'A[]'","value":"2"},{"name":"'A[]'","value":"10"},{"name":"'A[]'","value":"40"},{"name":"'A[]'","value":""},{"name":"'B[]'","value":"4"},{"name":"'B[]'","value":"8"},{"name":"'B[]'","value":""},{"name":"'B[]'","value":""},{"name":"'C[]'","value":"64"},{"name":"'C[]'","value":"26"},{"name":"'C[]'","value":""},{"name":"'C[]'","value":""}]

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct html and jquery code to get the requested json result?
I don't want to refresh the whole page but only get the requested result and display it with console.log().
Thank you

Comment: What have you done so far? where's your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

1) about array keys: if you need them, you can generate the keys of the array with PHP (for,foreach), because javascript doesn't generate integer keys in this way (for  PHP they are generated by default from the PHP naming convention):

```
$fields = 3;

for($n=0; $n<$fields; $n++)
{
   echo '<select class="form-control" name="A['.$n.']">';
   echo '</select>';
}
```

2) Handling of the data with javascript in case of the same name as the form control:

```
var myForm = document.forms.hetfo_form;
var myData_a = myForm.elements['A[]'];
for (var i = 0; i < myData_a .length; i++) {
    var aData = myData_a [i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_string = $('your_form').serialize();
```

More info you can find here - [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)